# Boolean Difference Tool Not Changing Shape

Tags: modifiers, boolean-modifier

So I'm designing the head model for a video game character, and my boolean tool stopped working.

I'm trying to subtract two UV Mesh Spheres from a complex shape in order to create eye sockets like so:

[image: The head model and the spheres I'm subtracting]

When I overlap the shapes and try to do the Boolean Difference, for some reason it does not subtract the sphere from the face of the object (lets call it "skull"), but half of the sphere still exists inside the shape (what would be the back of the eye socket).

[image: Boolean diff attempt (front view)]

Can someone please show me how to fix this? It's really slowing down my project, and I don't want to start playing with the vertices.

Comment: Please upload your blend file (http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), this will make it easier to answer your question.

Comment: Looks like two overlapping objects, are you sure your don't have two 'skull' meshes overlapping?

Comment: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2047

Comment: Duarte- Thought of that, already went through the process of deleting duplicates and using control N to fix the mesh.

Comment: I've just had a similar issue. I have a cube that I move around and subtract it from my main figure. However, after the second boolean difference applied, it stops working. Starting from scratch leads to the same issues. Seem like a bug to me - no error, no nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to comment but looking at the blend file you posted, it looks like the normals on both objects are flipped inside out. Using "Make Normals Consistent" on both meshes [seems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DC3L7.png) to make it work okay.

You said you already did this, though. Perhaps the "Inside" checkbox is checked for you? I didn't see that in the blend file you posted though so I'm not really sure. But the skull mesh in your screenshots and both the meshes in the blend file you posted are definitely inside out, you can tell from the weird purple black thing they've got going on.

[image]